# Horizontal Scaling Mechanism

Tags: cloud, cluster-computing, autoscaling

In the world of modern cloud computing, horizontal scaling normally stands for adding/removing instances are per the **current** application load. However, normally launching of a new instance normally takes one or two minutes and in case of extremely sudden load increase (or even a DOS attack) such scaling may not be fast enough and lead to existing application processes dying. How would you mitigate such cases ? Would you keep a few spare nodes ? Would you predict the increase (if possible) ? Or prepare for possible events (such as Black Friday's) by adding additional machine power in advance ?

If possible, I would like to hear on possible solutions, as well as the comments on the questions listed above.

This question might be too broad, and I will edit/elaborate if required.

Comment: Why would the existing processes die? At worst, and overloaded server should start rejecting incoming connections until the additional nodes are up.

Comment: @sudo let's assume that due to insufficient control over the system processes CPU/memory usage utilisation goes above predefined limits and application hangs/dies. But it does not matter, i.e. the eventual target is to satisfy as much of user requests as possible